# how do i achieve ActivityOptions.setLaunchDisplayId(1) marshmallow in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to open another app in a second screen(POS) so kindly help me to run another app in side second screen. I got the code for Oreo but I need this to work from Lollipop to latest.

```
ActivityOptions options = null;
Intent launchApp = MyApplication.getInstance().getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
launchApp.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic().setLaunchDisplayId(1);
        MyApplication.getInstance().getActivity().startActivity(launchApp, options.toBundle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a nested conditional check for the SDK version that the device is running when you should just move the nested conditional check to the parent and remove the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M` part.

Answer (score 0):

Android did not support showing multiple apps very well back on Android 5.0. All that you could do was:

- Have one app use both screens, either by default mirroring or by using `Presentation`; or
- Use something like [my `PresentationService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) to have your app use the secondary display from the background, while a "regular" app uses the primary display

You may wish to discuss your ideas with the device manufacturer, to see if they have other device-specific alternatives.